# Is it possible to make multiple jQuery Ajax Calls with one one server-client communication

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a program in which i am experimenting with Ajax.

The general idea is i have an array or Elements where i am doing a jQuery call for each of those elements using `jQuery.ajax`. Now the server does a Db call for each of those calls.

So the flow is something like below

```
Client Request 1---->Server call1---->DB--->Server reply1--->Client Response 1
Client Request 2---->Serve call2---->DB--->Server reply2--->Client Response 2
Client Request 3---->Server call3---->DB--->Server reply3--->Client Response 3
```

Is it possible to have a staggered or incremental response from server for one Ajax call so it would be something like

```
Client Request 1,2,3---->Server call 1---->DB--->Server call1---><Server call 2---->DB--->Server reply2---><Server call 3---->DB--->Server reply3--->Client Response 1,2,3
```

Comment: You could create a single request that has a message telling the server to retrieve elements 1,2, and 3 then the server parses that request, makes the appropriate calls, and returns all three elements in the response

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called **comet**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

I haven't seen it used before, but I was researching it because I may need it for one of my own projects.  The basic principle of comet is that you send a request to the server and over a long period of time various responses are written back to the client over the same connection.

Note that there are several different ways that you can implement this.  Some allow cross-site scripting, some do not.  You will need to research which method(s) work best for your requirements.